# How to append data into queue with multithreading (takes only last row and duplicate it)?

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

I have a file that has 1m+ transactions (csv) that I need to clean from extra spaces and validate the input type (like: int, float,...).

I'm passing chunks of rows each time and start a thread to process the data. When the thread finishes, it takes another chunk to process and so on till the chunks are finished. but the issue that the final look over the queue, it has only the last processed row * number of rows (1.01m transactions).

I tried to declare the queue globally, nothing changed.
I tried to print the results before it goes to queue, it shows theme in the correct results but put it wrong in my queue.
I tried to use a global list instead but it was highly not recommended because of the nature of threading.

threading call:

```py
threads = []
for chunck in reader:
   threads.append(threading.Thread(target=clean , args=([chunck, queue])))
   threads[-1].start()

for t in threads:
   t.join()
```

cleaning function:

```py
def clean(i, queue):
    details = {}
    for index, column in i.iterrows():
        for key,val in column.items():
            if isinstance(val, str):
                details[" ".join(key.split()).replace(" ","_").replace('.','').lower()] =  " ".join(val.split())
            else:
                details[" ".join(key.split()).replace(" ","_").replace('.','').lower()] = val
        queue.put(details)
        # queue.task_done()


    return queue
```

I expect to have the total number of rows cleaned and putted in the queue so I can generate the final cleaned csv. but now, it gives me a file with 1.01m transactions with the same value of last processed row.

Answer (score 0):

As I got great help from python community in Reddit.

The issue was with the cleaning function, that I declared the dict outside the first loop, which I should declare it inside the first loop.

Code:

```py
 def clean(i, queue):

    for index, column in i.iterrows():
        details = {}
        for key,val in column.items():
            if isinstance(val, str):
                details[" ".join(key.split()).replace(" ","_").replace('.','').lower()] =  " ".join(val.split())
            else:
                details[" ".join(key.split()).replace(" ","_").replace('.','').lower()] = val
        queue.put(details)
        # queue.task_done()


    return queue
```

The issue happened that the dict in all cases are duplicated whenever the threading is finished.